# Наложение полупрозрачного цвета на background-image

Tags: css

Как на картинку наложить цвет с прозрачностью в 0.3 (например, красный) на `background-image: url();`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/h8ekayuu/

HTML

```
<div class="img">
    <div class="img-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.img{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: url(http://vmeste.eu/fun/1142791216.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}
.img-overlay{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Comment: W3C дала вам псевдоэлементы, а вы городите блоки, зачем? ( http://jsfiddle.net/h8ekayuu/1/ )

Answer (score 5):

Ответ от @ДмитрийВасильевич был верный, но нужно поменять местами градиент и фоновое изображение:

```
background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,0,0,0.3), rgba(255,0,0,0.3)),
  url(http://vmeste.eu/fun/1142791216.jpg);
```

Изображение идущее в коде выше перекрывает изображение идущее ниже.

Также можно по отдельности для градиента и изображения задать прочие фоновые свойства:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
background-size: cover, contain;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background: url(http://vmeste.eu/fun/1142791216.jpg), linear-gradient(to, top, rgba(255,0,0,0.3), rgba(255,0,0,0.3));
```