# Задать фоновой цвет поверх фонового рисунка

Tags: css, css3

Делаю так, но фоновая картинка налаживается на цвет а не  располагается под него.

```css
form{
    width: 770px;
    height: 442px;
    background: black url(../images/буф.jpg)0/90% no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Я делал поверх картинки блок

Comment: Несколько фоновых картинок как вариант     background: 
     url( images/aztec_block.png) 0 0 no-repeat,
     url(images/aztec_block.png) -576px 100% no-repeat, 
     url(images/aztec_block.png) -288px 0 repeat-y;

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,0,0,0.3)),
      url(../img/своё изображение);
```

Идея автора на **[Наложение полупрозрачного цвета на background-image](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/373574/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-background-image)**

Answer (score 1):

Один из самых удобных способов, на мой взгляд - наложение внутренней тени без размытия. В отличие от множественного фона позволяет задать фоновую картинку атрибутом. А по сравнению с псевдой меньше писанины.

```css
.example{
  min-height: 400px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100vw rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="example" style="background-image:url(https://bit.ua/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/image-12-1200x630.jpg)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Только стилями **css** никак. Нужно создавать элемент поверх картинки

```css
.form {
  display:block;
  width:770px;
  height:442px;
  background-image: url('http://www.fullhdoboi.com/wallpapers/thumbs/6/kartinka-apelsiny-1885.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}
.form:before {
  display:block;
  content: '';
  position:absolute;
  background-color:black;
  width:770px;
  height:442px;
  opacity:0.6;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
</div>
```